# HDMI accepts Audio at 48000 Hz But Not 44100 Hz

Tags: sound, hdmi

I am trying to resolve why my HDMI is failing on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.   I have finally found a test that produces the problem  consistently.  Audio (eg MP3) that is encoded with a sampling rate of 48000 Hz or even 8000 Hz is played without any problem.  But if the audio is encoded with a sampling rate of 44100 Hz there is total silence.  In both cases the video component is displayed fine.

Does anyone know why HDMI audio would be accepting 48000 Hz and rejecting 44100 Hz?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
In desperation I have now purchased a mini displayport to HDMI converter and connected this to the notebook’s mini displayport which is located alongside the HDMI port..  The Ubuntu notebook is now able to send audio of all sample rates that I have tried to a HDMI monitor.  The only conclusion I can come to is that my HDMI port on the notebook is defective and that different sets of audio data lines are needed depending on the sample rate (or some other attribute of the mp3 files that I am currently unaware of.)
As a sanity check I have replicated this whole experience with Windows 10 installed on the notebook.  Exactly the same results.

Anyone else have any suggestion as to what could be going on, other than a bad HDMI port?